# Programmatically (via. Credit Memos?) Clean-up Paypal Reversal in Magento

Tags: magento, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been asked to look into a weird paypal problem a colleague is seeing on a Magento site w/r/t to paypal transactions.  Specifically, if paypal flags a website payments standard transaction as possibly fraudulent and reverses the charges, it sends Magento a **Reversal** request via the IPN URL

```
http://store.example.com/paypal/ipn
```

which updates the order financials after a reversal and makes a note in the order history.

My colleague is reporting that Magento also attempts to automatically create a credit memo to zero out the order, but that the amounts are always off due to paypal fee charges.  Because of this the order can't be closed out, and the stock remains tied up.

Unfortunately this happened months ago and we've gone beyond paypal's 28 day window for IPN logs. I'm setting up a paypal sandbox now to run some test transactions.

Before I get too deep into the code here

1. Is this a known thing?
2. Is there a known way to configure, or otherwise programmatically manipulate paypal/magento so this is handled seamlessly
3. Are there third party programatic solutions that can automatically clean-up these orders?
4. Any other thoughts, warnings, or gotchas before I wade in too deep are appreciated

**Magento Version**: 1.5.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to extend paypal return method and add comparison against order total and manipulate the sum returned from paypal to match order total

Comment: That's the plan if no answer comes through here.  It seems like something someone might have already solved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with order processing in magento and paypal specifics. But if you look into Magento 1.6.0.0-rc2 (Jul 11, 2011) release notes, you will see next 2 paypal related fixes:

1. Automatically cancel order after the expiration of Order Valid Period (maybe, your orders will be canceled and products returned to stock?)
2. Fixed Orders placed through PayPal marked as “Suspected Fraud”

   - Added formatting amount into comparing (not sure if it is related to your problem)